# How to upgrade python 3.8.0 to 3.8.3 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I upgraded the python version from 3.6 to 3.8.  However the python version it installed was 3.8.0 and I want 3.8.3.

```
$ sudo python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

How do I upgrade to 3.8.3?

Comment: This method might help you with upgrading to 3.8.3 also: https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/

Comment: Don't reboot your computer! It might fail to start! Different versions of Python are not alternatives on Ubuntu, so you should revert that change ASAP.

Comment: What ever you do, don't apt remote python3.6 like I did. A lot of dependencies get removed as well. On reboot your network interfaces don't even come up.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to install it. The latest version for 18.04 is currently [3.8.3-1+bionic1](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=3.8&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

However, you should make sure that `python3` points to the system version of Python (i.e. 3.6), since different versions are not alternatives on Ubuntu, and that can break your system (examples [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/301745), [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/301745), [3](https://askubuntu.com/q/686177/301745)). You'll need to use `python3.8` to run Python 3.8 in the future.

Answer (score 1):

as the manual says, [compile from source](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#getting-and-installing-the-latest-version-of-python) , since deb packaging is a bit behind actual releases

Comment: See https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. It seems to have latest versions. User could add deadsnake PPA and then install 3.8.3 without needing to compile from source. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Update `python3 3.6` to `python3 3.8` version
Steps:

- 1. Check python version  `python3 -V`
- 2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
     `sudo apt-get update`
- 3. `apt-get update`
- 4. Verify the Python updated or not `apt list | grep python3.8`
- 5. Install the Python 3.8 `sudo apt-get install python3.8`
- 6. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1`
     `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2`
- 7. `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
- 8. Now type 2 and hit enter
- 9. `python3 -V`

Now you can see python3 updated with 3.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade my python package from 3.8.15 to 3.8.17 on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, for that I used the following steps (upgrading a specific python package from the source directly :

- Update your system's local repository list by running:

```
sudo apt update
```

- Install supporting dependencies on your system with APT:

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

- change directory to /opt and store the downloaded python source files there:

```
cd /opt
```

OR
Make a new directory to store the Python source files:

```
mkdir ./python && cd ./python
```

- Download the Python source code from the official FTP server ([download here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/)) :

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.17/Python-3.8.17.tgz
```

- Extract the TGZ file that you just downloaded with:

```
tar -xvf Python-3.8.17.tgz
```

- You need to perform tests and optimizations before installing Python. This is important as it increases the execution speed of your code by at least 10 percent:

```
cd Python-3.8.17
./configure --enable-optimizations
```

- Build the package using the MakeFile present in the directory:

```
sudo make install
```

After you've implemented these steps, check if Python was installed properly on your computer by typing python3 --version in the terminal it should now show 3.8.17.

Hope this helps! Thanks!
All credits go to the following blog post from where I got and used this approach ([here](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-python-ubuntu/))